# Uber deeplink call not accepting pickup and dropoff parameters

Tags: uber-api

My method for launching the Uber from within my app is working.  It takes me to the "setPickup" page, it shows the start/pickup address but its not showing the dropoff/destination even though I am providing it.

Because my GPS is on, though, I don't know if the pickup is correct because its accepting my pickup parameters being passed to it or if its simply using my device's GPS.

Here is my call to the Uber app:

> uber://?action=setPickup&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&pickup[latitude]=27.875107pickup[longitude]=-82.489036&dropoff[latitude]=27.9425974&dropoff[longitude]=-82.45189249999999&product_id=37a94557-682f-4562-ba62-2448f80d3ddd

I am able to select different types of uber via the passed parameters, UberX, UberSelect, etc...thus it all appears to be working except for the dropoff portion.  The uber app shows the pickup, but just says "Destination" looking for an address to be entered.

NEW ISSUE: 
Well, its almost working, I am testing this across New York city as NY has more Uber pickup services than any other city (I am aware of).  When I get the products info I am using that to pass to the deeplink.  As best as I can tell I am specifically calling for uberX yet its defaulting to uberPool.

I tested further...it isn't uberX specific.  Its happening ONLY on the first uber app launch, no matter what product is selected - every time it defaults to uberPool.  If I back out of uberApp back into my own, and click uberX or any other uber Service - it then takes me to the appropriate service screen.

If I close my app, restart and load uber services - the issue repeats.  First time default to uberPool, then all subsequent ride selections open the uber app and take me to the correct service that was selected from within my app.

Whats up this...please don't tell me its an uber feature?  :-(

```
0:
{capacity: 2, product_id: "929fcc19-8cb4-4007-a54f-3ab34473700f", price_details: null,…}
capacity:2
description:"Share the ride, share the cost"
display_name:"uberPOOL"
image:"http://d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net/car-types/mono/mono-uberpool.png"
price_details:null
product_id:"929fcc19-8cb4-4007-a54f-3ab34473700f"
shared:true
short_description:"uberPOOL"

1:
{capacity: 4, product_id: "b8e5c464-5de2-4539-a35a-986d6e58f186",…}
capacity:4
description:"The low cost Uber"
display_name:"uberX"
image:"http://d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net/car-types/mono/mono-uberx.png"
price_details:{service_fees: [], cost_per_minute: 0.35, distance_unit: "mile", minimum: 8, cost_per_distance: 1.75,…}
product_id:"b8e5c464-5de2-4539-a35a-986d6e58f186"
shared:false
short_description:"uberX"
```

And my deeplink call: 
`uber://?action=setPickup&client_id=MY_CLINET_ID&product_id=b8e5c464-5de2-4539-a35a-986d6e58f186&pickup[latitude]=40.759078&pickup[longitude]=-73.986201&pickup[formattted_address]=205%20W%2046th%20St,%20New%20York,%20NY%2010036,%20USA&pickup[nickname]=New%20York%20Marriott%20Marquis&dropoff[latitude]=40.7118011&dropoff[longitude]=-74.01311959999998&dropoff[formatted_address]=World%20Trade%20Center,%20New%20York,%20NY,%20USA&dropoff[nickname]=World%20Trade%20Center`

Answer (score 2):

In order to set a dropoff destination, you must also specify either a dropoff nickname or formatted address. The parameters are `dropoff[nickname]` and `dropoff[formatted_address]`, respectively.

See this Github issue for some more context: https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk/issues/1

Comment: ahhh, interesting, they do not do reverse geo-coding.  Ok, adding in [formatted_address] now.  As far as [nickname] is concerned, I hope it doesn't require that.  I have no idea what my users are going name things.  :P

Comment: found a bizarre issue...added the notes and findings to the bottom of the above problem.

Comment: @JohnBrophy : Hi, can I open uber from my app with dropoff and pickup location without adding sdk?